# text-shadow anomaly IE10+

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, cross-browser

In my website I'm having a strange bug. When checked on Internet Explorer the home page text is hidden from a certain point. I checked this with IE11 and before versions until IE9. IE9 text did not disappear and was shown correctly. I did not understand why until I played with the text-shadow element.

If I take out the text-shadow with the inspector the text is shown correctlt. Therefore this text-shadow is creating this disappearing effect. so... what the heck is the problem and how to solve this? Really desperate...

This is the online website, test with IE t see the disappearing effect: http://cepods.com/

This is the effect that occurs:
[image]

Comment: IE.. you have done it yet again.

Comment: The site is already online and it works except on IE due to the text-shadow. As I cannot check on the internet for solutions I really do not know what to do. Maybe take text-shadow is the only solution, but I find that a bit crap solution... maybe you have a better solution?